# How to prove (x,y) is a minimal/maximal element of AxB if x∈A is a minimal/maximal element and y∈B is a minimal/maximal element

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, order-theory

Not exactly sure what to do here.

I'm assuming that since x ∈ A and y ∈ B then we can assume that (x,y) ∈ AxB.

Not sure what I'm stuck on. Can we not just say that since x and y are minimal, then (x,y) is minimal in AxB?

Comment: How is A×B ordered?

Comment: Book says assume AxB is product ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the product order, we have

$$(x,y) ≤ (x′, y′) \qquad≡\qquad x ≤ x′ \;∧\; y ≤ y′$$

Recall
$$ m \text{ minimal } ≡ (∀ m′ \,•\, m′ ≤ m \;⇒\; m′ = m) $$

So, for any $x′, y′$ we calculate:
\begin{align}
     &   (x′, y′) ≤ (x, y)       
\\ ≡ &  \text{ \{ Product Order definition \} }
\\   &   x′ ≤ x  \;∧\;  y′ ≤ y   
\\ ≡ &  \text{ \{ Both $x,y$ are minimal \}  }
\\   &   x′ = x  \;∧\;  y′=y    
\\ ≡ &  \text{ \{ Equality of pairs \} } 
\\   &  (x′, y′) = (x, y)
\end{align}

Hence $(x, y)$ is minimal provided each $x, y$ is minimal.

Comment: Okay thats kind of what I wrote down on my paper. Thank you!

Comment: @WilliamElliot Please explain where? I'm using the definitions from Wikipedia, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements